# Get litecoin testnet transactions of a single litecoin testnet address programatically

Tags: node.js, blockchain, litecoin

I want to get the associated transactions of litecoin testnet address in the litecoin testnet address using node js. So far haven't found any resources to do so. Can anybody have an idea how to implement this?
p.s. I wanted to do it in a way other than to host litecoin node myself.